# Load a specific Android library based on API version

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library

I used to include an Android library on Eclipse, say `lib-1.jar`, to my app that supports all devices from API 8.

Now the news: the latest version of this library supports only Android from API 9 (`lib-2.jar`). I don't want to drop the support for API 8, and at the same time I need this new version. Is it possible to tell Android to load `lib-1` or `lib-2` depending of the current API version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jars` are not usually loaded at runtime. You either need to have these libs complete separate from each other and in different packages and then do conditional use in your code, or just build two different APKs, using different jars while building

Comment: I thought so... I just needed a confirmation. Thanks

Comment: jar files are usually not loaded at run-time but they can be loaded!